# Implement Content-Based Routing Using a Business Rules Policy for a Known Message Type does not work using Samples

Tags: routes, biztalk

I'm fairly new to Biztalk and the ESB Toolkit, We have since tried to implement content based routing via an ESB Itinary but I am having problems with the condition on the business rule not evaluating properly, I've been following the microsoft example in the link below but it just doesn't want to work. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264380%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx

When we submit a request we get the following error, meaning the rule has not evaluated.
Can someone please help?

The map name was not provided and is required.

Source: Microsoft.Practices.ESB.PipelineComponents.DispatcherDisassemble

Method: Void Disassemble(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage)

Error Source: Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Services

Error TargetSite: Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage ExecuteTransform(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage, System.String, Boolean)

Error StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Services.TransformationService.ExecuteTransform(IPipelineContext context, IBaseMessage msg, String mapNameOrResolverString, Boolean validateSource)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Services.TransformationService.Execute(IPipelineContext context, IBaseMessage msg, String resolverString, IItineraryStep step)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.PipelineComponents.DispatcherDisassemble.Disassemble(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg)

Answer (score 0):

John,

In certain cases you may indeed encounter this known issue. It does not seem to be a bug but rather a side effect of the way the ESB Toolkit is engineered.

Basically, for content-based routing to work, you need to re-write your Business Rules so that the message type (or more appropriately SchemaStrongName) is [Microsoft.Practices.ESB.ResolveProviderMessage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/biztalkesb/thread/42a6bb79-c070-41fe-8732-28748dbce68a). Ideally, you would need to have two set of rules : one with the "correct" message type, and another one with the one expected by ESB Toolkit.

You can have a look at [my article on my blog](http://maxime-labelle.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D8D9369449D177DA!334.entry) for more information.